# Accessing vdc from shell

Tags: recovery-mode

I am trying to change my device encryption password by opening a terminal in TWRP and typing `vdc changepw default_password 1234` and it's giving me `vdc: inaccessible or not found`.

Is there something wrong with my approach or is the issue with the phone?

Comment: `vdc` won't work in recovery. It's a dynamic binary in `/system/bin` which links to libraries in `/system/lib`. Usually this doesn't happen automatically in recovery mode. But even if you manage to do so, `vdc` is just a small wrapper to communicate with the actual bigger service `vold`. But in recovery mode OS and hence its services are not running. So many of Android's commamdline tools don't work in revovery mode, including `am` and `pm`.